# DataTable Issues on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I need some help to solve my latest problem on HTML with DataTables.

I'm showing up a table with the with only two columns (name and local).

I imported the "required" files (CSS and the JS):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the part of my HTML code that "draws" the table:

```
<div class="tabela">
      <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-lg-1" style="background:#1a4669; color:white; font-size: 16px; text-shadow: none;"> Name </th>
            <th class="col-lg-1" style="background:#1a4669; color:white; font-size: 16px; text-shadow: none;"> Local </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="listview">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

The data of the table is imported at the end of the `<body>`, which I fill the table in the `<tbody>`:

```
  <script src="./js/clients.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The problem is there is no data detected, but it's there!

I will leave a screenshot:

[![Display][1]][1]

Do anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks

My clients.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var url2="http://localhost:8080/CS-Management/php/clients.php";
      $.getJSON(url2, function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i,field){
          var idclient = field.idclient;
          var code = field.code;
          var name=field.name;
          var local=field.local;

         if ((i % 2) == 0){
            $("#listview").append("<tr style='background:#FFFFFF'><td><a style='color:inherit; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color:#3357C3; a:hover {background-color: yellow;}' class='item' href='myclient.html?idclient="
            + idclient + "'><div style='height:100%;width:100%'>" + nome

            +"</div></a></td><td><a style='color:inherit;font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color:#3357C3' class='item' href='client.html?idclient="
            + idclient + "'><div style='height:100%;width:100%'>" + localidade

            +"</div></a></td></tr>");
          }

          else if ((i % 2) != 0) {
            $("#listview").append("<tr style='background:#D9E8F5'><td><a style='color:inherit; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color:#3357C3' class='item' href='myclient.html?idclient="
            + idclient + "'><div style='height:100%;width:100%'>" + nome

            +"</div></a></td><td><a style='color:inherit;font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color:#3357C3' class='item' href='myclient.html?idclient="
            + idclient + "'><div style='height:100%;width:100%'>" + local

            +"</div></a></td></tr>");
          }

        });
      });
});
```

Comment: Your javascript code for the datatable?

Comment: Add the content of your client.js and then i can help you

Comment: It is quite posible you are instantiating your DataTable before the asynchronous request returns a response. Make sure you initiate the DataTable instance on your XHR 'onload' event handler callback. Have in mind that this is a wild guess and you should include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will offer you much better answers.

Comment: @JoseMarques updated!

Comment: @GbemigaOgouby updated!

Comment: First for using datatables you can use this plugin that facilitates connection. Link: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html

Comment: Second in your code you use var name and var nome and name!=nome

Comment: Where are you initializing DataTable? `$("#myTable").DataTable();`

Comment: In the thirteenth place where you started your datatable. As @Riky pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments:

> You are instantiating your DataTable before the asynchronous request
>   returns a response. Make sure you initiate the DataTable instance in
>   your XHR 'onload' event handler callback.

---

In your clients.js you need to initiate the DataTable plugin once the asynchronous request is successful, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url2 = "http://localhost:8080/CS-Management/php/clients.php";
  $.getJSON(url2, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      var idclient = field.idclient;
      var code = field.code;
      var name = field.name;
      var local = field.local;

      if ((i % 2) == 0) {
        $("#listview").append("<tr style='background:#FFFFFF'><td><a style='color:inherit; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color:#3357C3; a:hover {background-color: yellow;}' class='item' href='myclient.html?idclient=" + idclient + "'><div style='height:100%;width:100%'>" + name

          + "</div></a></td><td><a style='color:inherit;font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color:#3357C3' class='item' href='client.html?idclient=" + idclient + "'><div style='height:100%;width:100%'>" + localidade

          + "</div></a></td></tr>");
      } else if ((i % 2) != 0) {
        $("#listview").append("<tr style='background:#D9E8F5'><td><a style='color:inherit; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color:#3357C3' class='item' href='myclient.html?idclient=" + idclient + "'><div style='height:100%;width:100%'>" + name

          + "</div></a></td><td><a style='color:inherit;font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color:#3357C3' class='item' href='myclient.html?idclient=" + idclient + "'><div style='height:100%;width:100%'>" + local

          + "</div></a></td></tr>");
      }

    });
    //Initialize the DataTable plugin here.
    $("#myTable").DataTable();
  });
});
```

---

*Notes:*

- The variable `nome` does not exist, it is misspelled, use `name`.
- The variable `localidade` might be a misspell too (`local`).
- You could avoid code repetition and use classes instead of the style
  attribute in your `if` statements.